# Failed to build Solidity contract: exec: "solc": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

I'm executing below command:

```
abigen --sol helloworld.sol --pkg main --out helloworld.go
```

But getting below error:
Failed to build Solidity contract: exec: "solc": executable file not found in $PATH

When I check echo $PATH, solcjs is present.

```
echo $PATH
/home/edureka/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/edureka/.local/share/umake/bin:/home/edureka/bin:/home/edureka/.local/bin:/home/edureka/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin:/home/edureka/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/edureka/.local/share/umake/bin:/home/edureka/bin:/home/edureka/.local/bin:/home/edureka/.local/share/umake/bin:/home/edureka/bin:/home/edureka/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/edureka/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/solcjs
```

How I can solve this error?

Comment: Can you please check if you have `solc` bin in this path? /home/edureka/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/solcjs abigen is trying to find `solc`, not `solcjs`.

Comment: solc isn't on your $PATH you can either add it to your $PATH or set the environment variable SOLC_BINARY to the path to the solc executable

Answer (score 2):

You have to install `solc` not `solcjs`.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/installing-solidity.html

> The comandline options of solcjs are not compatible with solc and tools (such as geth) expecting the behaviour of solc will not work with solcjs.

You have to install a binary package - https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/installing-solidity.html#binary-packages

Answer (score 1):

You should install solc. Check [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.2/installing-solidity.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly due to solc specific version not in your path.

## To see which version of solc

```
solc --version
```

## where is your solc installed ?

```
whereis solc
```

## Add the output of the above command to your PATH.

```
   export PATH=$PATH:{output_from_above_command}
```

This should resolve your solc not present in the PATH issue.

Please note that you need specific version tag. 0.7.6 or 0.8.0 etc... Any typos will not pick correctly.